# using only 1 for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

is it possible to do they following using only one for loop instead of 2:

```
int index = ws.getLastRowNum() + 1;
List<AdditiveList> list=new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=1; i<index; i++){
        list.add(new AdditiveList());
}

for(AdditiveList x: list){
         Row row=null;
         if (rowIterator.hasNext())
             row=rowIterator.next();
         x.inputAdditiveData(row);
         x.outputData();
 }
```

Comment: Here's a tip: keep your indentation consistent to make your code more readable. At first glance it appears the loops are nested. The second loop should not be indented so far out.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is possible.

try this -

```
int index=ws.getLastRowNum()+1;
List<AdditiveList> list=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1; i<index; i++){
    AdditiveList additiveList = new AdditiveList();
    Row row = null;
    if(rowIterator.hasNext())
        row = rowIterator.next();
    additiveList.inputAdditiveData(row);
    additiveList.outputData();
    list.add(additiveList);
}
```

---

In case `rowIterator.hasNext()` returns false, in that case list will add null value. If that is correct not according to requirement then you should ommit the null like below -

```
for(int i=1; i<index; i++){
    if(rowIterator.hasNext()){
       Row row = rowIterator.next();
       AdditiveList additiveList = new AdditiveList();
       additiveList.inputAdditiveData(row);
       additiveList.outputData();
       list.add(additiveList);
    }        
}
```

Comment: This does the exact same work as the original code, but there is a problem in the original and here: If rowIterator.hasNext() returns false, you are appending nulls to the end of your list. Maybe that's what you want, but it might make more sense just to stop adding to the list.

Comment: I also thought the same, and I think I should add this comment too, thanks @AnnKilzer